# What is the tenacious badge?

Tags: support, badges

According to the description of the tenacious badge:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

"Zero score" make sense; the answer was accepted without an up vote.

But what does "more than 5 and 20% of total" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you need to have six or more accepted zero score answers, and those must at least make up 20% of all your accepted answers to get the badge.

From [the list of all badges and descriptions on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258):

> #### Tenacious
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Have more than five accepted answers with a score of zero, and have those zero-score accepted answers account for at least 20% of all your accepted answers

Comment: Small correction; anyone can get 20% zero score answers, it's the accepted flag that counts ;-)